# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end error when I make sitemap

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, sitemap

I got "sitemap.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" in my rails project.

I am making sitemap with using sitemap_generator gem. 
I don't recognize which "end" is missing.

Here is the code

**sitemap.rb**

```
# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "myaddress"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = '-------'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'public/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new(
                                         fog_provider: 'AWS',
                                         aws_access_key_id: '------',
                                         aws_secret_access_key: '------',
                                         fog_directory: '-------',
                                         fog_region: '-------'
                                         )
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do


  add '/organization', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/service', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/help', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/1', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/2', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/3', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/4', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/5', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/6', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/7', :changefreq => 'weekly'
  add '/category/8', :changefreq => 'weekly'

  plan.find_each do |plan|
    add plan_path(plan), :lastmod => plan.updated_at
  end

  Spot.find_each do |spot|
    add spot_path(spot), :lastmod => spot.updated_at
　end

  Feature.find_each do |feature|
    add feature_path(feature), :lastmod => feature.updated_at
　end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, it looks fine.

Comment: @vanhiro It seems 'plan.find_each' should be 'Plan.find_each'

Comment: Did you try to call `add` method like this ? `add(plan_path(plan), :lastmod => plan.updated_at)`

Answer (score 1):

`aws_secret_access_key: ------`, should be `aws_secret_access_key: '------'`,

Answer (score 0):

There is a U+FFE3 FULLWIDTH MACRON character in front of the second to last `end`. Since that is a legal character in a Ruby identifier, that is not parsed as the `end` keyword but rather as a call to a method named 　`end`.